# Why webkit notification event does not trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webkit, jquery-events

I have wrote a webkit notification script on my web app to pull notifications from a database. The code is seen below:

```
function checkNotifications() {
    if (window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() == 1) {
        window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission();
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/check_notifications',
            success: function(data){

                if (data){
                    var ticketId = data.ticket_id;
                    console.log(data);
                    var comment = data.comment;
                    var createdDate = data.created_at;
                    var notificationComment = data.comment;
                    var notificationId = data.notifcation_id;
                    var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification('/pt_logo_small.png', 'Project Ticket '+ticketId+ ' Updated!', 'Ticket has been updated. Click here to see!');     
                    notification.show();
                    console.log(notificationId);

                    notification.onclick = function(){
                        this.close();
                        console.log("NOTIFICATION WAS CLICKED!")
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: '/read_notifications/' + notificationId,
                            success: function(){
                                window.location = '/pto/' + ticketId;
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                window.location = '/pto/' + ticketId;
                            }
                        });
                        
                        console.log(ticketId, comment, createdDate);
                    };
                }

            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout(checkNotifications, 20000);
}
```

For some reason. I if select another tab, or go to another path inside my webapp, the script still runs to display the notifications, however the `.onclick` event never triggers.

Anyone have any idea why the even wouldn't trigger?

According to [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Articles/SendingNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012932-SW6), `onclick` should bring the page which created the event to focus, which it does. However nothing inside my `.onclick` function triggers.

Comment: Try setting the onclick event before showing the notification.

Comment: tried but made no difference unfortunately :-(